# Terminate function with timeout

Tags: c++, linux

I have a third party library. This library has function named `int foo()`. Function is thread based and I cannot change the content of the function. (It does not belong to me.)

When I call the function, it becomes locked and does not return the value. Is there any way to kill this thread based function, when the function is locked? For example, when the function doesn't return the value within 5 seconds, I want to kill it without any memory leak.

Comment: You can always start the function on yet another thread you *do* control.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah but to abort the thread could result in memory leaks since you do not know where the running code is in its execution.

Comment: @Neijwiert, the extra thread the OP created doesn't need to be terminated after the timeout. I'm aware there is a delicate matter of resources here.

Comment: What is that third-partly library, and what is that particular function `foo`? With practical details, we could help more.

Comment: You can't portably do that, moreover, you will introduce leaks if the thread mallocs/news objects... The only way to do so is to spawn another process, give it a timeout, then request the OS to kill the process after 5 seconds

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah right, stupid me. That would solve both problems but still would take up system resources, because it continues to compute in the background.

Comment: @Neijwiert, yes. But there is no silver bullet in this case, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can always do it in a separate process. Well maybe not "always" but give it a try. What's your OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since its a third party library which you have no control over, you cannot portably terminate the thread that runs that code, though you can call for the `native_handle` and use its thread termination facilities, you will most likely introduce **leaks**.

Note that, threads live in the same Address space, hence a corruption or a leak from one thread affects your entire program.

The option I can think of is to spawn a new process to run that code, if after 5 seconds it doesn't complete, you can request the OS to kill it. {No memory leaks and resources are freed} :-) ...your best choice...

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, as suggested by [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller), is to call `foo()` in a different thread, which you control. When timeout happens, you leave the thread running in the background. This means `foo()` continues execution, but your program can continue. This method is portable, so you don't need to write any operation system dependent code.

Leaving `foo()` running can have unwanted side effects, and `foo()` will continue to use resources in the background, so you have to test whether this works in your situation.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <ctime>

void FooWrapper(bool& hasResult, int& result){
    result = foo();
    hasResult = true;
}

void AnotherFunction(){
    bool hasResult = false;
    int result;
    boost::thread(&FooWrapper, boost::ref(hasResult), boost::ref(result));

    // Wait until result, or until timeout
    std::time_t startTime = time(0);   
    while(!hasResult && time(0) < startTime + 5){
        // Do nothing
    }
    if(!hasResult){
        throw "timeout";
    }
    else{   
        // Use result
    }
}
```

I am using boost thread here, but you can convert it to use any thread library you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but foo running and using resources.  My question is related to memory leak and free the resources.

Comment: @MelihAltıntaş With this approach, there is no memory leak, assuming foo will eventually return. For example, if execution of foo takes 30 seconds, resources will be freed after 30 seconds, even though your timeout was at 5 seconds. Of course, if you want to free those resources _immediately after timeout_, then this solution will not work.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do so without memory leaks, because the thread running `foo` may allocate heap data, might put some private data inside values owned by your main program or some other thead.

Notice that data liveness (and [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)) is a whole-program property: some heap data does not belong to a (particular) thread, but to the whole process. The library could (and probably should) use smart pointers as a *convention*.

Comment: Just thinking here, not sure if this would work. But could you override the new operator?

Comment: @Neijwiert, it won't help if the third party library is built separately.

Comment: @StoryTeller it depends on the platform. Should normally work on Posixy systems but not Windows.